How to create a new column to categorize products based on distinct combination of another columns with NULL values
I have a MySQL 5.7 table that stores products. The node columns refer to categories and subcategories. Among these nodes, only node_0 and node_4 are guaranteed to be non-NULL, while the others may or may not be NULL. This table will be used to process products in batches based on unique combinations of their node values (unique_cat). Each unique combination can have between 1 and 50 products. The individual node names are not unique (i.e., node_i can have the same name as node_k), but the combinations of these nodes are unique.
One reproducible example is as follows:
    CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    node_0 varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
    node_1 varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
    node_2 varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
    node_3 varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
    node_4 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO products (node_0, node_1, node_2, node_3, node_4) VALUES
('a_0', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a_1'),
('a_0', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a_1'),
('a_2', 'a_1', NULL, NULL, 'a_1'),
('a_0', NULL, NULL, 'a_3', 'a_2'),
('a_3', NULL, NULL, 'a_0', 'a_2'),
('a_0', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'a_2'),
('a_2', 'a_1', NULL, NULL, 'a_1')

I need to create a new column, unique_cat, which will be a number representing distinct values of the combination of node_0, node_1, node_2, node_3, and node_4. I'm unsure how to handle NULL values in this context.
Expected output:
| node_0 | node_1 | node_2 | node_3 | node_4 | unique_cat |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|
| a_0    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | a_1    | 0          |
| a_0    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | a_1    | 0          |
| a_2    | a_1    | NULL   | NULL   | a_1    | 1          |
| a_0    | NULL   | NULL   | a_3    | a_2    | 2          |
| a_3    | NULL   | NULL   | a_0    | a_2    | 3          |
| a_0    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | a_2    | 4          |
| a_2    | a_1    | NULL   | NULL   | a_1    | 1          |

When dealing with only node_0 and node_4, the following approach works:
# Create a unique combination of node_0,node_4 with unique IDs
unique_cat_df = df \
      .select("node_0", "node_4") \
      .distinct() \
      .withColumn("unique_cat", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Join the unique combinations back to the original DataFrame
df_with_cat_ids = df.join(
      unique_cat_df,
      on=["node_0", "node_4"],
      how="left"
)

However, when I try to include nodes that can be NULL, it doesn't work as expected. Here’s what I have tried:
placeholder = "___NULL___"
df = df_0 \
    .withColumn("node_2", F.when(col("node_2").isNull(), placeholder).otherwise(col("node_2"))) \
    .withColumn("node_3", F.when(col("node_3").isNull(), placeholder).otherwise(col("node_3")))

# Select columns and create distinct combinations with a unique ID
unique_combinations_df = df \
    .select("node_0", "node_1", "node_2", "node_3", "node_4") \
    .distinct() \
    .withColumn("unique_cat", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Join the unique combinations back to the original DataFrame
df_with_ids = lastest_data_df_2.join(
    unique_combinations_df,
    on=["current_node", "node_1", "node_2", "node_3", "root_node"],
    how="left"
)

This approach is not working. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!
Update: Solved!
After a lot of head-scratching, coffee breaks, and contemplating the meaning of life, I discovered the culprit behind my code not working as expected:
 drumroll 
I forgot to replace NULL values in node_1! 
Shame on me... 

I don't understand how you're calculating unique_cat in your example. In row 6, there are 2 values, a_0 and a_2, how do you get unique_cat = 4?

The unique_cat is just a number that categorize the combinations of node_0,...., node_4. Created by using distinct(node_0,....,node_4)

So it's just a consecutive index created for each new combination?

Yes, it is just that. I don't know why it returns unique_cat with NULLs when trying for all the nodes.

I'm not sure how to do this, but it will almost certainly be easier if you normalize the data instead of using multiple columns.

Oh, I just realized I forgot to add node_1 in my code!  By the way, I'm planning to follow your advice on normalization. Do you think something like this could work? Products: (product_id, product_name), nodes: (node_id, product_id, node_level, node_value) -> primary(node_id), foreing(product_id).

Please create an answer under this post that worked for you and solves this question and accept it so that it may help others as well.

There are some more direct ways to accomplish this without using placeholder and distinct(), but the best method will depend on the Spark version. Which Spark version are you using?

I have added an answer to showcase the idea of having an output column that represents the unique node values. The answer below incorporates this concept, while also providing you with the requested output for the unique_cagetory column
Step 1: Aggregate
Aggregate the values for each row into a unique set of values for that row.
df_array = df.withColumn("node_array", F.array(F.col("node_0"),
                                                    F.col("node_1"),
                                                    F.col("node_2"),
                                                    F.col("node_3"),
                                                    F.col("node_4"))
                             )\
                  .withColumn("node_array_clean", F.filter(F.col("node_array"), lambda x: x.isNotNull()))\
                  .withColumn("node_array_distinct", F.array_distinct(F.col("node_array_clean")))\
                  .withColumn("unique_node_values", F.array_sort(F.col("node_array_distinct")))
df_array.show(truncate=False)

Output



product_id
node_0
node_1
node_2
node_3
node_4
node_array
node_array_clean
node_array_distinct
unique_node_values




1
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, null, null, null, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]


2
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, null, null, null, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]
[a_0, a_1]


3
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_2, a_1, null, null, a_1]
[a_2, a_1, a_1]
[a_2, a_1]
[a_1, a_2]


4
a_0
null
null
a_3
a_2
[a_0, null, null, a_3, a_2]
[a_0, a_3, a_2]
[a_0, a_3, a_2]
[a_0, a_2, a_3]


5
a_3
null
null
a_0
a_2
[a_3, null, null, a_0, a_2]
[a_3, a_0, a_2]
[a_3, a_0, a_2]
[a_0, a_2, a_3]


6
a_0
null
null
null
a_2
[a_0, null, null, null, a_2]
[a_0, a_2]
[a_0, a_2]
[a_0, a_2]


7
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_2, a_1, null, null, a_1]
[a_2, a_1, a_1]
[a_2, a_1]
[a_1, a_2]



What this is doing,
Order of Operations:
node_array -> node_array_clean -> node_array_distinct ->  unique_node_values
[a_2, a_1, null, null, a_1] -> [a_2, a_1, a_1] -> [a_2, a_1] -> [a_1, a_2]

node_array: uses F.array to collect the values for the columns
node_array_clean: uses F.filter to remove the nulls from our collected values

If using Spark 3.4+ use array_compact for this step


node_array_distinct: uses F.array_distinct to remove duplicates

I was not sure if keeping these duplicates was important, this step can be removed if the duplicates are important for your use case


unique_node_values: uses F.array_sort to order the values in the array

I was not sure if the order that the value were reported in was important, this step can be removed if this matters for your use case



Why this is useful,
The unique_node_values column represents an ordered list of unique values for each row. It gives us the ability to now look up all rows that have a specific value using a statement like,
df_array.select("product_id", "unique_node_values")\
    .filter(F.array_contains(F.col("unique_node_values"), "a_1"))\
    .show()




product_id
unique_node_values




1
[a_0, a_1]


2
[a_0, a_1]


3
[a_1, a_2]


7
[a_1, a_2]



Step 2. Clean Up
Let's remove the columns we no longer require, to make things easier to read. 
df_clean = df_array.drop("node_array")\
    .drop("node_array_clean")\
    .drop("node_array_distinct")

Another option is to nest the functions of Step 1 in order to only create one column. In this answer I created multiple columns to make it easier to follow along
Step 3. Create the unique_category id column
Define a window function to use when ranking, we can order by the unique_node_values that was previously created
window_spec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("unique_node_values")

The choice between rank and dense_rank would depended on your use case for the final unique_category, below you can see how their outputs vary
Example using rank
df_ranked = df_clean.withColumn("unique_category", F.rank().over(window_spec))
df_ranked.show(truncate=False)




product_id
node_0
node_1
node_2
node_3
node_4
node_array_ordered
unique_category




1
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, a_1]
1


2
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, a_1]
1


6
a_0
null
null
null
a_2
[a_0, a_2]
3


4
a_0
null
null
a_3
a_2
[a_0, a_2, a_3]
4


5
a_3
null
null
a_0
a_2
[a_0, a_2, a_3]
4


3
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_1, a_2]
6


7
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_1, a_2]
6



Example using dense_rank
df_ranked = df_clean.withColumn("unique_category", F.dense_rank().over(window_spec))
df_ranked.show(truncate=False)




product_id
node_0
node_1
node_2
node_3
node_4
node_array_ordered
unique_category




1
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, a_1]
1


2
a_0
null
null
null
a_1
[a_0, a_1]
1


6
a_0
null
null
null
a_2
[a_0, a_2]
2


4
a_0
null
null
a_3
a_2
[a_0, a_2, a_3]
3


5
a_3
null
null
a_0
a_2
[a_0, a_2, a_3]
3


3
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_1, a_2]
4


7
a_2
a_1
null
null
a_1
[a_1, a_2]
4



Considerations
Things to consider with the use of rank, dense_rank, and monotonically_increasing_id is that these ID columns could change when the input data differs. The value of 1 could represent a node combination of [a_0, a_1] with the data you have today. If the data changes, the value of 1 could be assigned to represent a different node combination (e.g. [a_0]).

Thanks for your answer. Suppose there is an array [a1, Null, Null, Null, a2]. Would this approach consider it the same combination as [Null, a1, Null, Null, a2]? I need it to be considered as a different combination. Can you give me a hint?

This approach would consider them the same. If you want them to be considered different, you could use the node_array column from Step 2 in Step 3, to create the unique_category ID column.
